# Rxjs do something on first emit from multiple subscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Is there a clean way to do something on first emit from multiple subscriptions ?

**e.g.**:

```
this.subscription1 = this.service.getData1().subscribe(data => {
    this.data1 = data;
    console.log('1');
});

this.subscription2 = this.service.getData2().subscribe(data => {
    this.data2 = data2;
    console.log('2');
});

// Do something after first emit from subscription1 AND subscription2
doSomething();

...

doSomething() {
    console.log('Hello world !');
}
```

**Output goal**:

```
1
2
Hello world !
1
2
1
1
2
1
2
2
...
```

Comment: Try `combineLatest`: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I think `forkJoin` would be a slightly better choice here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There've multiple times where I also needed such a `isFirst` operator that'll run some predicate only for the first emission. I've slapped together a quick custom operator that uses a single state variable `first` to decide if the emission is indeed first and run some predicate using the `tap` operator.

Since it uses `tap` internally it does not modify the source emission in any way. It only runs the passed predicate when the emission is indeed first.

Try the following

**`isFirst()` operator**

```js
export const isFirst = (predicate: any) => {
  let first = true;
  return <T>(source: Observable<T>) => {
    return source.pipe(
      tap({
        next: _ => {
          if (first) {
            predicate();
            first = false;
          }
        }
      })
    );
  };
};
```

For combining multiple streams that will be triggered when *any* of the source emits, you could use RxJS `combineLatest` function.

Example

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { timer, Observable, Subject, combineLatest } from "rxjs";
import { tap, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `<button (mouseup)="stop$.next()">Stop</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  stop$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
    combineLatest(timer(2000, 1000), timer(3000, 500))
      .pipe(
        isFirst(_ => {
          console.log("first");
        }),
        takeUntil(this.stop$)
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: r => console.log("inside subscription:", r)
      });
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular10-rxjs-isfirst-operator?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

In your case it might look something like

```js
this.subscription = combineLatest(
  this.service.getData1().pipe(
    tap({
      next: data => {
        this.data1 = data;
        console.log('1');
      }
    })
  ), 
  this.service.getData2().pipe(
    tap({
      next: data => {
        this.data2 = data;
        console.log('2');
      }
    })
  )
).pipe(
  isFirst(_ => { 
    console.log("first"); 
  })
).subscribe({
  next: r => console.log("inside subscription:", r)
});
```

Comment: Sounds nice ! Wouldn't `forkJoin` be better to run subscriptions in parallel ?

Comment: `forkJoin` will only emit when the sources are complete. So if you were to do something in the subscription or some operators below the `forkJoin`, they won't be hit till all the observables are complete. And the subscription callback will only get the complete. Moreover `combineLatest` also does trigger all the source observables in parallel. The difference is in the way the notifications are emitted to the subsequent operators and the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest strategy is to have a 3rd `Observable` that will perform this action.

See below example

```typescript
const Observable1$ = timer(1000, 2000).pipe(
  map(() => 1),
  tap(console.log)
);
const Observable2$ = timer(1700, 1700).pipe(
  map(() => 2),
  tap(console.log)
);
const Observable3$ = combineLatest([Observable1$, Observable2$]).pipe(
  take(1),
  map(() => "Hello World!"),
  tap(console.log)
);
Observable1$.subscribe();
Observable2$.subscribe();
Observable3$.subscribe();
```

The console output is as per below, since there are two subscribers to `Observable1$` (i.e `Observable1$` and Observable3$`same as two subscribers to`Observable2$`(i.e`Observable2$ `and Observable3$` we see console logs 1 1 2 2 'hello world ...'

[image]

[Here is the link to the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kdossd?devtoolsheight=60)

In the above we notice that we get 2 subscriptions hence 2 console logs for each. To solve this we can use `Subjects` to generate new Observables and combine these instead

```typescript
const track1Subject$ = new Subject();
const track1$ = track1Subject$.asObservable();
const track2Subject$ = new Subject();
const track2$ = track2Subject$.asObservable();
const Observable1$ = timer(1000, 2000).pipe(
  map(() => 1),
  tap(console.log),
  tap(() => track1Subject$.next()),
  take(5)
);
const Observable2$ = timer(1700, 1700).pipe(
  map(() => 2),
  tap(console.log),
  tap(() => track2Subject$.next()),
  take(5)
);
const Observable3$ = combineLatest([track1$, track2$]).pipe(
  take(1),
  map(() => "Hello World!"),
  tap(console.log)
);
Observable1$.subscribe();
Observable2$.subscribe();
Observable3$.subscribe();
```

[image]

[See Link to final solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-psnffu?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 0):

With some further restrictions, this problem becomes easier. Unfortunately, operators like `combineLatest,` and `zip` add extra structure to your data. I'll provide a solution with `zip` below, but it doesn't extend at all (if you want to add more logic downstream of your `zip`, you're out of luck in many cases).

#### General solution.

Assuming, however, that `getData1` and `getData2` are completely orthogonal (How they emit and how they are consumed by your app are not related in any predictable way), then a solution to this will require multiple subscriptions or *a custom operator tasked with keeping track of emissions*.

It's almost certainly the case that you can do something more elegant than this, but this is the most general solution I could think of that meets your very general criteria.

Here, I merge the service calls, tag each call, and pass through emissions until each call has emitted at least once.

```
merge(
  this.service.getData1().pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log('1')),
    map(payload => ({fromData: 1, payload}))
  ),
  this.service.getData2().pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log('2')),
    map(payload => ({fromData: 2, payload}))
  )
).pipe(
  // Custom Operator 
  s => defer(() => {
    let fromData1 = false;
    let fromData2 = false;
    let done = false;
    return s.pipe(
      tap(({fromData}) => {
        if(done) return;
        if(fromData === 1) fromData1 = true;
        if(fromData === 2) fromData2 = true;
        if(fromData1 && fromData2){
          done = true;
          doSomething();
        }
      })
    );
  })
).subscribe(({fromData, payload}) => {
  if(fromData === 1) this.data1 = payload;
  if(fromData === 2) this.data2 = payload;
});
```

In the subscription, we have to separate out the two calls again. Since you're setting a global variable, you could throw that logic as a side effect in the tap operator for each call. This should have similar results.

```
merge(
  this.service.getData1().pipe(
    tap(datum => {
      console.log('1')
      this.data1 = datum;
    ),
    map(payload => ({fromData: 1, payload}))
  ),
  ...
```

#### The `zip` Solution

This solution is much shorter to write but does come with some drawbacks.

```
zip(
  this.service.getData1().pipe(
    tap(datum => {
      console.log('1')
      this.data1 = datum;
    )
  ),
  this.service.getData2().pipe(
    tap(datum => {
      console.log('2')
      this.data2 = datum;
    )
  )
).pipe(
  map((payload, index) => {
    if(index === 0) doSomething();
    return payload;
  })
).subscribe();
```

What is passed into your subscription is the service calls paired off. Here, you absolutely must set a global variable as a side effect of the original service call. The option of doing so in the subscription is lost (unless you want them set as pairs).